# Irrelevant rule breaks ANTLR4 grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I'm building an ANTLR4 grammar to parse strings from a data source - similar, if not pretty much the same as StringTemplate, except I don't like that syntax so I'm writing my own (also just for fun and learning, as this is my first experience w/ ANTLR).  My grammar currently looks like this (this is simplified from what I actually have, but I've verified that it is a "good example" and exhibits the same problem I'm asking about):

```
grammar Combined1;

file: 
    .*? (repToken .*?)+
    | .*?
    ;

foreach: '@foreach' WS* '(' WS* repvar WS* ')' WS* '{' content=file '}' ;
with: '@with' WS* '(' WS* repvar WS* ')' WS* '{' content=file '}' ;
// withx: '@withx' WS* '(' WS* repvar WS* ')' WS* '{' content=file '}' ;

repvar: '@' (
    '$'
    | '(' nestedIdentifier ')'
    | nestedIdentifier 
    ) ;

repToken:
    foreach
    | with
    // | withx
    | repvar
    ;

nestedIdentifier: Identifier ('.' Identifier)* ;
Identifier: [A-Za-z_] [A-Za-z0-9_]* ;
WS: [ \t\r\n] ;
Other: ( . ) ;
```

This grammar works just fine, allowing me to perform replacements such as:

```
string template = "Test: @foreach(@list){@$}";
Process(template, new { list = new [] { "A", "B", "C" } });
```

and the result would be:

```
Test: ABC
```

(The mechanics of how I process the tree to get this result are relatively simple but not relevant to the question, so I'm not providing that code.)

My question is this...  if I include (uncomment) the "withx" rule right below the `with:` rule, ***and I forget to include (uncomment) the `withx` to the alternatives in `repToken`*** then my example above breaks, even though it has absolutely nothing to do with `withx`.  Once I add `withx` as an alternative to `repToken` then my example works again.  Why??

Here's what I know:

- Regardless of whether `withx` is included or not, my lexer correctly
  returns 12 tokens: `Test`, `:`, `' '`, `@foreach`, `(`, `@`, `list`,
  `)`, `{`, `@`, `item`.  This isn't surprising as I've only added a
  parser rule, and not touched the lexer tokens (aside from adding the
  one implicit token '@withx').
- Before I add the `withx` rule, my
  parser correctly groups all the tokens after @foreach as children of
  the ForeachContext, resulting in a FileContext with 4 children (3
  TerminalNodeImpl and a RepTokenContext).
- After I add the `withx`
  rule, my parser for some reason doesn't recognize the rest of the
  tokens as belonging to ForeachContext, resulting in a FileContext
  with 10 children, none of which is a ForeachContext, but which has
  all TerminalNodeImpl with 2 RepTokenContext corresponding to @list
  and @$.

I'm completely baffled why adding a parser rule that doesn't have anything to do with my input would cause my parser to fail.  Help!?

**EDIT 3/17/2014:** JavaMan asked for a parse tree in each scenario to clarify the description above.  I don't know how to generate the parse tree graphic that he did, but here's two screenshots from Visual Studio debugger illustrating the difference...   Note that in these images I use longer names - specifically, ReplacementTokenContext is for repToken.

The first one is when I DO include `withx` in the alternative list (note that the tree is essentially FileContext -> ReplacementTokenContext (node index 3) -> ForeachContext):
[image: Visual Studio Watch when I include withx]

And the second is when I DO NOT include `withx` in the alternative list (note that the tree is essentially FileContext -> TerminalNodeImpl "@foreach" (node index 3):
[image: Visual Studio Watch when I DO NOT include withx]

Comment: You should get rid of the non-greedy wildcard(s) `.*?` in your parser rules for performance reasons.

Comment: 280Z28: For now, I think I need the greedy wildcards because I'm not just parsing a language - I'm performing replacements of variables within strings.  Thus, I need every single character that's in the original string.  I've been reading the ANTLR book and I realize that I may be able to use Island grammars to help, but I'm not there yet.  :)

Comment: I need to do something similar for StringTemplate parsing in ANTLR 4. The lexer is defined by [TemplateLexer.g4](https://github.com/sharwell/antlrworks2/blob/master/org-antlr-works-editor/src/org/antlr/works/editor/st4/experimental/TemplateLexer.g4) and [TemplateLexer.java](https://github.com/sharwell/antlrworks2/blob/master/org-antlr-works-editor/src/org/antlr/works/editor/st4/experimental/TemplateLexer.java), and the parser by [TemplateParser.g4](https://github.com/sharwell/antlrworks2/blob/master/org-antlr-works-editor/src/org/antlr/works/editor/st4/experimental/TemplateParser.g4).

Comment: 280Z28: OK thanks I'll try to look thru that to figure out how to improve my version.  As I said, this is my first attempt w/ ANTLR (or any lexer/parser tool for that matter) so it might be a bit complicated for me to get thru - I'm learning in baby steps.  Right now I'm just trying to understand why including this 'withx' rule breaks my parse tree when I see no reason for it to do so.

Comment: See my edit. I'm using the Java target only which has a tool call TestRig to generate the parse tree.  It seems that the 2 versions of grammar produce just the same parse tree in Java.

Comment: 280Z28: OK so now that I realize you are Sam (which explains why you answer so many ANTLR questions on SO!) I would ask you to comment on the details revealed in the comments below JavaMan's answer.  To summarize: when I compile my grammar using antlr4cs, the parse tree is not correctly generated (when not including withx in the alternative list), but when I compile it to a Java target and inspect w/ TestRig -gui, it does create a correct parse tree.  It seems to me that this is a bug, but I don't know how to report it formally (I see no way to do it), or if our discussion here is enough?

Comment: By all means, report any bugs you've found using this github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues

Answer (score 1):

With your whole grammar plus the `withx` rule and the 2 lines of input, I am able to obtain this parse tree node `repToken` grouping the @foreach input text under a `foreach` node:
[image]

It looks like a correct parsing to me.  Is this what your want? Could it be a problem with your visitor code? Did you get the same parse tree?  It would be better if you could post your parse tree here.

By the way, what about sending all whitespaces to a hidden channel and delete all the WS tokens from the parser rules?

**EDIT**:

I'm using ANTLR4 V4.1 with Java target only so I cannot be sure if it is a bug with the C# target or v4.2. But both grammars give me the same parse tree in Java.  There is a tool called TestRig (at least in Java target) that can generate the parse tree in either GUI or ASCII form:

```
java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig Combine1 file -tree in.cpp > treeres.txt
```

By running the above command using the 2 versions of grammar you mentioned and the same input file, I got the same ASCII representation of the parse tree:

```
(file string   template   =   " Test :   (repToken (foreach @foreach ( (repvar @ (nestedIdentifier list)) ) { (file (repToken (repvar @ $))) })) " ; \r \n Process ( template ,   new   {   list   =   new   [ ]   {   " A " ,   " B " ,   " C "   }   } ) ;)
```

The graphical output is too big so I don't include them here. So at least in Java, the same parse tree is generated with or without the `withx` rule.

I suggest you to double check with the TestRig tool or try verifying with the Java target.

Comment: JavaMan: Yes, that's the correct parse tree that I am expecting, and yes, that's what I get when I DO include the 'withx' in the repToken alternatives. But as I mention in the description, I do NOT get the same parse tree when I DO NOT include 'withx' in the repToken alternatives - I get a bunch of TerminalNodeImpl's as children of the FileContext. That's the point of my question - I don't see why including this 'withx' or not including it has ANYTHING to do with a correct parse of the input provided.  I've updated the question with some screenshots that hopefully clarify.

Comment: BTW also, it definitely cannot be a problem with any of my C# code - I'm simply looking at the results of the parser, before my code does anything with the parse tree.

Comment: As for the whitespace issue, I realize that there's probably better ways to accomplish my need, which is that I need to get all of the whitespace provided.  I'm not familiar enough w/ hidden channel yet to know whether this would work - it's something I will investigate.

Comment: Hmm!!!   You are indeed correct - I was able to get the java target installed and running, and I've verified that the example does seem to give the correct parse tree, regardless of whether 'withx' is included in the alternatives list.  Is it possible I've come across a bona-fide bug in the C# target??  I am using the "4.2.0-alpha001 (Prerelease)" version of the C# Visual Studio add-in (via NuGet).  Should I report this via Sam Harwell's project page (https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs)??

Comment: By all means, report any bugs you've found using this https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues

Comment: So I was all ready to "submit" my issue as you suggested, and I decided to explain one additional difference I saw between Java and C# - the fact that Java tree was showing \r and \n, but my parse tree (even when correct) didn't have it.  The `Process(template...` code in my question isn't input - it's how the tree gets generated.  As you can see, it's just a string input - there is no terminating `\r\n`.  However, when I add it explicitly, my parse tree works!!  This shows that I cannot compare the Java tree to the C# tree - I suspect Java tree would show the same problem if I drop those....

Comment: ...characters, but I don't know how to do that since the EOF ^Z needs to be on a new line by itself.   But it still doesn't explain why when withx isn't included, that the parse tree breaks.  So now I'm not at all sure if it's a problem with my grammar or truly a bug.  I just don't know how to proceed except to say that I know how to fix it for myself, and if this truly is a bug then Sam will have to step in if he's still monitoring or someone else smarter than I will have to take up the cause.  :(